# Atom-light collision inconsistency of conservation of laws

Tags: electromagnetism, classical-mechanics, conservation-laws

Consider light moving to the right in a vacuum, with momentum and energy

$$p=\hbar k$$
$$E = \hbar \omega = \hbar c k$$

Now the interesting part. Consider an atom or large classical particle moving to the left. It is moving slowly so the doppler effect isn't an issue. It momentum and energy are

$$p = m v$$
$$E = \frac12 m v^2$$

How many $N$ collisions are needed to bring the atom to a stand-still? The light is fully absorbed by the atom.
By conservation of momentum, it is (rounding up)

$$N_p = \frac{p_{atom}}{p_{photon}} = \frac{mv}{\hbar k}$$

By conservation of energy, it is (rounding up)

$$N_E = \frac{E_{atom}}{E_{photon}} = \frac{\frac12 m v^2}{\hbar c k} = \frac12 \frac v c  N_p$$

I don't see a problem with the momentum conservation, and think the energy picture is wrong. In this case, what is missing in the calculation of $N_E$?

Comment: Why are you assuming the collision is elastic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your momentum argument is OK, as you suspect, but the energy argument does not describe what actually happens.

Each photon is absorbed so the energy of the atom, or large classical object,  **increases**. Quantum mechanically it gets pushed into an excited state: macroscopically its temperature would rise.

So equating the initial KE with the energy absorbed has no basis, and it's not surprising it gives an arbitrary (wrong) answer.

Answer (score -1):

Your question is classical formulated, like 2 balls colliding. But your case is really QM stuff.

In a classical collision experiment you always have conservation of momentum. But you only have conservation of energy if the collision is inelastic (bounce off). In case of elastic collision the deformity of the objects releases heat therefore energy is not conserved.

In a QM scenario you would only be able to get a maximum 2 photons of the same frequency absorbed (absorbed = collision is elastic). The missing overall kinetic energy is this case goes to an electron that jumps from lower to a higher energy level.

Laser cooling might be of interest for you.